# How do I set a Java Calendar to a specific UTC time?

Tags: java, calendar

When I do this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
c.set(9999, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a");
String date = formatter.format(c.getTime());
assertEquals("31-Dec-99 00.00.00.000000000 AM", date);
```

I get this:  30-Dec-99 18.00.00.000000318 PM

How do I get the time I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [formatter's time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) as well before performing the format.

```
formatter.setTimeZone(c.getTimeZone());
```

Otherwise it will use the platform default time zone.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the calendar doesn't hold nano seconds, so that part may still be a bit off after formatting.

Comment: GAAA.  I have just been schooled twice on Calendar/Timestamp/Formatters!  Thanks!

Comment: Yes - in particular, the "318" shows that the milliseconds haven't been reset to 0, too.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a `SimpleDateFormatter` without specifying the time zone - so it will use the system local time zone by default. If you want the formatter to use UTC as well, simply set it.

Note that a `Date` value is time zone agnostic - it's *just* the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It has no idea what time zone was originally used to create it. That's why you need to call `setTimeZone` on the formatter (or use a constructor which takes a zone).

The 318 in the milliseconds shows that your original `Date` value contains a milliseconds component of 318. A `java.util.Date` only supports a resolution of milliseconds anyway, so you should use `SSS000000` in your format... and you should set the millisecond value to 0 anyway:

```
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

(Annoyingly, setting "year, month, day, hour, minute, second" doesn't reset the millisecond value. Seems crazy to me, but...)

As a side note, the built-in Java date/time API is pretty grim in various ways. You may well want to look into using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead...